# How to merge all sound sources together?

Tags: audio, windows-11

Windows 11 shows several **sources** of sound separately, with the ability to set the volume of each one independently:

[image]

This setup is in my case particularly annoying because when I switch devices, I sometimes end up not being able to manage the volume level directly (via the keyboard or the headset buttons) because different devices are attached as the sound source and as "device that is managed by the buttons".

In other words, I have a high volume in my headset, try to lower it, but something else is actually toned down and I need to go to the window above to find the source and manage it form there.

My question: is there a way to disable this "volume mixer" and just have the ability to manage the current sound source (as it was in the past)?

Comment: The top speaker one should be the overall volume.

Comment: @LPChip good to know, thanks. The problem is rather that there is sometimes a disconnect about the "physical volume buttons" (keyboard, headset) and the source of the sound. Thus my question about disabling the mixer.

Answer (score 0):

Windows can sometimes assign audio devices like a headset to a separate "type". Check your output devices in Settings > System > Sound, and click on the arrow to the right of the device you want to control. Take a look at the option named "Set as default device". This value can be:

1. Is default for audio
2. Is default for communications
3. hidden (when set to default for both audio and communications)
4. Not used as a default

The volume up/down buttons only adjust the overall volume for the current default **audio** device (1 and 3). If your audio is coming through a "communication" type of app (voice chat or calls usually), the keyboard volume keys may not affect it.

If that is the issue, you can fix it by setting a single device as the default for both audio and communications.